# Object reference error adding a new select list item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, selectlistitem

I'm having a problem with the `List<SelectListItem>`. Whenever the code hits the `foreach` it says:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Am I missing something or can anyone explain why it is failing there?

```
public ActionResult HammerpointVideos(string category, string type)
{
    var stuff = Request.QueryString["category"];

    var ItemId = (from p in entities.EstimateItems
                  where p.ItemName == category
                  select p.EstimateItemId).FirstOrDefault();

    var Videos = (from e in entities.EstimateVideos
                  where e.EstimateItemId == ItemId
                  select new Models.HammerpointVideoModel
                  {
                      VideoName = e.VideoName,
                      VideoLink = e.VideoLink
                  }).ToList();

    var model= new Models.HammerpointVideoListModel();
    List<SelectListItem> list = model.VideoList;

    foreach (var video in Videos)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Selected=false,
                        Value = video.VideoLink,
                        Text = video.VideoName
                    });

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your model class look like? Are you initializing `VideoList`?

Comment: What's the exact line where error triggers?

Comment: Yes, I assumed he meant Videos was null, also, is it? Debug!

Comment: the only thing I see is that your linq is asking `where e.EstimateItemId == ItemId`...but ItemId isn't an int type, it's an unspecified `var`.  I have no idea if that is the issue, but if it is, then the reason your code doesn't work is because it can't distinguish the VALUE of `ItemId`, and so the second linq block returns no results.  I may be way off however.  Other people?  Is this a possibility?  I haven't touched LINQ in a year, so I'm a bit rusty there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `ViedoList` initialized before? I assume it is not. Create new list add items to it and after that add reference to it in your model:

```
var model = new Models.HammerpointVideoListModel();
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var video in Videos)
{
    list.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Selected=false,
                    Value = video.VideoLink,
                    Text = video.VideoName
                });

}

model.VideoList = list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably You didn't initialized `VideoList` in the parameterless constructor of `HammerpointVideoListModel` class, so it is NOT an empty list.

Put

```
VideoList = new List<SelectedListItem>();
```

in the constructor.